# What does the error rate mean in Naive Bayes.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, matlab, bayesian

Can anyone explain what the Bayes error rate is in Naive Bayes, for instance in matlab:

```
[class, err]  = classify(UnseenTestdata, training_data, target_class,'diaglinear')
```

I get an error rate (`err`) of **0.5040** what does this mean? Im not a math orientated person so plain english would help. Is this good, bad or very ugly?

Answer (score 1):

From the matlab help function:

> Err is  an estimate of the
>       misclassification error rate that is based on the training data.
>       CLASSIFY returns the apparent error rate, i.e., the percentage of
>       observations in the TRAINING that are misclassified, weighted by the
>       prior probabilities for the groups.

So, if 0.5 is close to your guessing rate you are doing poorly, otherwise it's not bad.

Comment: How can you say your doing poorly but then say otherwise its not bad? At 50% accuracy across all classes its kinda rubbish. I had been thrown off because my accuracy from the confusion matrix was 81.49% but I had noticed that it classified the biggest body from the testdata correct (one class) while leaving alot of the other classes with almost 0% accuracy.

Comment: Not sure if i understand correctly, but as I read it you have the output of two methods. In this case you can just compare the results manually and determine which one is better.